# Using omniauth 0.3.2 with Twitter's API v1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

Twitter recently retired v1 of their api https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

On an older project, I haven't got around to updating to a newer version of Omniauth. How can I use omniauth v0.3.2 with Twitter's newer API? Will I have to upgrade to omniauth >1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try monkey patching the strategy responsible for Twitter. It worked for me but I would recommend further testing in your case.

```ruby
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Twitter < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth
      def user_hash
        # URL path was '/1/account/verify_credentials.json'
        @user_hash ||= MultiJson.decode(@access_token.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json').body)
      rescue ::Errno::ETIMEDOUT
        raise ::Timeout::Error
      end
    end
  end
end
```